# Wildcard with multiple values?

Tags: sql

I get these [Challenge on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-6)

> Write a query to print the list of CITY that start with vowels (a, e,
>   i, o, u) in lexicographical order. Do not print duplicates.

**My solution:**

```
Select DISTINCT(City)
From Station
Where City like 'A%' 
   or City like 'E%' 
   or City like 'I%' 
   or City like 'O%' 
   or City like 'U%'
Order by City;
```

**Other solution:**

```
select distinct(city) from station
where upper(substr(city, 1,1)) in ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

This is very clever, but I want to know, if are there any other ways to solve this?

Any kind of DB is OK.

Comment: You can use regular expressions if supported by your ODBMS.  However, the syntax varies by database.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it's a part of SELECT DISTINCT and it applies to the whole selected rows. (select distinct (c1), c2... eq. select distinct c1, c2... eq. select distinct c1, (c2)...)

Comment: The latter still needs an `order by`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions in MySQL / MariaDB:

```
select distinct city from station where city regexp '^[aeiouAEIOU]' order by city
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well with MySQL.
Can you solve this using OracleDB.

Comment: Thank you, I've found the solution in OracleDB
`select distinct city from station where REGEXP_LIKE(City, '^[aeiouAEIOU]') order by city;`

Comment: Great solution. Works well

Answer (score 0):

In SQLserver You can use a reg-ex like syntax with like:

```
select distinct city from station where city like '[aeuio]%' Order by City
```

Comment: Please specify dbms, so the rest of us knows!

Comment: Thank you, It works with SQLserver. Before asking this question, I've tried these, but with OracleDB.

@jarlh: I want to know how to solve with many DBMS :D About OracleDB, how can I solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: @TrungNM, I already know that, but why not also with which dbms a solution works?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server

```
select distinct city from station 
 where charindex ('a',CITY) =1
    or charindex ('e',CITY) =1
    or charindex ('i',CITY) =1
    or charindex ('o',CITY) =1
    or charindex ('u',CITY) =1
```